# Conjecture relating differential equation and sum of a function over partitions

Tags: co.combinatorics

The following is an addition to [A function from partitions to natural numbers - is it familiar?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132338/a-function-from-partitions-to-natural-numbers-is-it-familiar); the function $f(\lambda)$ as defined there, when summed over all partitions of n, gives an unexpected hit in  http://oeis.org/A232434. Checked up to n=36.

In short:
Define  $g(x, q)$ by  $$\frac{\partial g(x,q)}{\partial x}=g(x,q)^2 * g(q x,q),$$ 
with series $$g(x,q)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{ c_k(q) x^k}{k!},$$ 
define  $t_{n}=n(n+1)/2$; then the coefficient of $q^{t_{n-1}}$ in $c_{n+1}(q)$ is 
 $\sum{_{\lambda \in n}}{f(\lambda)}.$

examples:
f(n=2)=6 and $c_{3}(q) =q^3+2 q^2+6 q+6$ ; $q^{t_{1}} = q^1$ with coeff. =6.
Likewise f(n=3)=14 and $c_{4}(q) =q^6+2 q^5+6 q^4+14 q^3+22 q^2+36 q+24$ ;
$q^{t_{2}} = q^3$ with coeff. =14;

Remark that the differential equation has no closed form solution, but its series can be generated upto $x^n$ for any given n.

Question: are there any arguments to trust\distrust this conjecture? Can it be proved ?

correction 28/05/2014 22:02 CET:  the differntial equation has a product in the RHS, not a sum. Thanks to Pietro for spotting it.

Comment: If you are going to post here regularly, it would be nice if you looked into the ways to format mathematics on this website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: should look better now?

Comment: @NateEldredge: extra dollar signs left as an excercise to the poster?

Comment: That was something I missed when I was editing it.  It was my fault and not the OP's fault.  Sorry.

Comment: Better, thanks, but, what does $f(n=2)$ mean? Same thing as $f(2)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yes, I tried to be more explicit : f(n) at value n=2. Overkill becoming murky.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: function f takes a partition as argument; f(n=2) is intended to mean the sum of f over all partitions of n. Btw: conjecture tested overnight to n=52. Computationally, summing f over the partitions is much faster than iterating the differential equation. So, as 'counting' goes, the conjecture is not much good.

Comment: A typo? Comparing with the OEIS link, I guess the differential equation for $g$ has a product, not a sum, in the RHS.

Comment: @PietroMajer: indeed! I checked the Mathematica implementation, and that at least is correct. Well spotted. Apologies.